# Image backgrounds in InDesign PDFs have weird coloring on Preview

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf

I'm working on a PDF document in InDesign where the A-Master would have an an image with a seamless pattern as a background. However, after exporting, whenever I look at the PDF on Preview (but not in Adobe Acrobat), the image in the A-Master would have a weird color difference, like it would appear more saturated, compared to the rest of the document.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple's Preview application has **many** rendering issues. It should **never** be used for proofing professional-level PDFs.

If you need PDFs to appear accurate in Preview, dumb them down - RGB color, low to medium resolution images, no spot colors, no overprints or blending modes, etc.